# Building a simple website that outputs results from a CSV using user’s input

Tags: javascript, html, csv

https://levelup.gitconnected.com/building-a-simple-website-that-outputs-results-from-a-csv-using-users-input-bfcb782ced45

Hi, I am new to JavaScript. I came across this above tutorial and am trying to get it working so that i can then modify it for a little project i am working on. I hope to learn from it as I progress my project. I cant learn at the moment as I dont know whether its right or wrong.

I have created the html and JS file and have tested that they are linked. (I wrote an alert  in the JS file that got triggered in the html file. I also added a quick script that gave a text alert when the button was pushed in html file).

I believe I have the same CSV file that the author was using but I cant be 100%. I can only assume I have introduced some error in the JS file and therefore its not reading the CSV file correctly. I have been at this for days and come up with nothing. Any help greatly appreciated.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang=”en”>
<head>
<meta charset=”UTF-8">
<meta name=”viewport” content=”width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Document</title>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<div class=”container”>
<div class=”row”>
<div class=”col-md-12">
<h1 class=>Find Movies!</h1>
<h2 class=>Enter the name of an actor/actress to see his/her best movies!</h2>
<form id=”form”>
<input class=”form-control” id=”user-input” placeholder=”Enter actor/actress…”>
<button id=”button” class=”btn btn-secondary”>Find Movies!</button>
</form>

<table class="table" cellpadding="10">
<thead>

<tr>
<th scope="col">#</th>
<th scope="col">Movie</th>
<th scope="col">Rating</th>
<th scope="col">Year</th>
<th scope="col">Description</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<script src="app.js" charset="utf-8"> </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**JavaScript** (app.js)

```js
d3.csv("movies.csv").then(function (data) {
var movies = data;
var button = d3.select("#button");
var form = d3.select("#form");
button.on("click", runEnter);
form.on("submit", runEnter);

function runEnter() {

d3.select("tbody").html("") 

d3.event.preventDefault(); 

var inputValue = d3.select("#user-input").property("value");

var filteredMovies = 
movies.filter(movies => movies.actors.includes(inputValue));

<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/0.10.0/lodash.min.js"></script>
var output = _.sortBy(filteredMovies, 'avg_vote').reverse()

for (var i = 0; i < filteredMovies.length; i++) {
d3.select("tbody").insert(“tr").html(
"<td>" + [i+1] + "</td>" +
"<td>" + (output[i]['original_title'])+”</a>”+“</td>” + 
"<td>" + (output[i]['avg_vote'])+"</td>" +
"<td>" + (output[i]['year'])+"</td>" +
"<td>" + (output[i]['description'])+"</td" ) }
};
});
```

[Extract from movies.csv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jX1BM.png)

Comment: Not sure what the issue is but you need to watch your quotes. `”` points to using a tool like Word instead of a proper programmer's editor. Always use `'` and `"`

Comment: The problem is probably your loading of the csv file. If you check your browser's console, you can probably see an error message from d3 about being unable to load the csv file. That's because for this to work, your files need to be served from http://, while you're probably looking at them in a file:/// environment. Press F12 to open the browser's dev tools and check the console tab for errors.

Comment: it would be easier to help if you could post the actual text from the CSV - into your question

Comment: Also, look at your web inspector - under the network tab with the XHR subtab enabled you should be able to see if the CSV file is getting loaded (or it will show a file not found). You can also just put some `console.log()` statements in your code to see what is happening at any given point. Like `d3.csv("movies.csv").then(function (data) { console.log(data);  `. They output to the web inspector `console` tab.

Comment: Thanks folks, I'll try out all the suggestions tomorrow. I appreciate the help